# How can I edit a JSON file using Python?

Tags: python, xml, json, raspberry-pi

I've looked at several questions and made the appropriate changes, but my python script still isn't working.  Still very new to Python so I apologize if I'm making a simple mistake...

I'm currently sending an XML response to my webpage to display a value from my JSON file.  I tested the XML portion of the script and it works fine - but when I add the code to edit my JSON file, the XML response doesn't load.  Here's what I've got - what am I doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb
import json


with open('../../../var/www/data.json', 'r+') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    json_data[0]['A'] = '7'
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data))
    f.truncate()

with open('../../../var/www/data.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)

cgitb.enable()


print "Content-Type: text/xml"     
print # blank line, end of headers
print "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><inputs><data>"+data[0]["A"]+"</data></inputs>"
```

I also tried this...but it didn't work either:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb
import json

with open('../../../var/www/data.json', 'r') as f:
    json_data = json.load(f)
    json_data[0]["A"] = "7"

with open('../../../var/www/data.json', 'w') as f
    f.write(json.dumps(json_data))

with open('../../../var/www/data.json') as data_file:    
     data = json.load(data_file)

cgitb.enable()



print "Content-Type: text/xml"     
print # blank line, end of headers
print "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><inputs><data>"+data[0]["A"]+"</data></inputs>"
```

And here is my JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "A": "11",
        "B": "4",
        "C": "",
        "D": "basement",
        "E": "Digital",
        "F": "",
        "G": "",
        "H": "",
        "I": "",
        "J": "",
        "K": "",
        "L": "",
        "M": "",
        "N": "on",
        "O": "off",
        "P": "1"
    },
    {
        "A": "11",
        "B": "3",
        "C": "",
        "D": "Silver",
        "E": "Digital",
        "F": "",
        "G": "",
        "H": "",
        "I": "",
        "J": "",
        "K": "",
        "L": "",
        "M": "",
        "N": "ON",
        "O": "OFF",
        "P": "1"
    },
    {
        "A": "12",
        "B": "3",
        "C": "",
        "D": "Bench",
        "E": "Digital",
        "F": "",
        "G": "",
        "H": "",
        "I": "",
        "J": "",
        "K": "",
        "L": "",
        "M": "",
        "N": "ON",
        "O": "OFF",
        "P": "1"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include your error/console output next time.

In your second file:

- line 11 is missing a `:` at the end of the line

Comment: Fixed the colon - still not working.  Console in my browser says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.  Below is my new python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cgi
import cgitb
import json



#this worked to open the json file, rewrite it, and then open it again for reading
with open("../../../var/www/data.json", "r+") as jsonFile:
    data = json.load(jsonFile)
    data[0]["A"] = "2"
    jsonFile.seek(0)  # rewind
    jsonFile.write(json.dumps(data))
    jsonFile.truncate()

newJsonFile = open("../../../var/www/data.json", "r")
newData = json.load(newJsonFile)

cgitb.enable()


print "Content-Type: text/xml"     
print # blank line, end of headers
print "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?><inputs><data>"+newData[0]["A"]+"</data></inputs>"
```